# FormShow issue in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have created a form (Name: SubForm) with 2 radiobuttons on it. On any of radiobutton click another form (Name: MainForm) will be displayed. On the `SubForm.OnShow` event I have set the `radiobutton1.checked:= False; radiobutton2.checked:= False;`  But the SubForm will be displayed with radiobutton1 or radiobutton2 checked.

Any idea why checked property is not set to `False`?

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? Delphi 2010 (I'm not sure about previous versions) allows you to have all radio buttons unchecked.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention.. I m using Delphi 7.

Comment: By default, no RadioButtons are checked. Then, the radio buttons are checked in an exclusive way: this is the standard behavior of radio buttons - only ONE can be checked at once. So I was not able to reproduce any issue with Delphi 7. There should be something in your code, or you are guessing some wrong behavior of your radio buttons. Try to create a *new application* with a *new form*, in order to reproduce the issue, then post the code and exact behavior here, in order to reproduce.

Comment: the principe for the radioButton is to have always one and only one checked button if the parent is a radioGroup, is it the case ?

Comment: It very much sounds like you want an extra radio button captioned None which indicates that neither of the other options is to be selected.

Comment: @TLama: Just to be clear: There was no mention of `TRadioGroup` in the question asked AFAICT, and you can have radio buttons on their own without using a radio group. Without the radio group, there is no `ItemIndex` to be set.

Comment: @Ken, yep, sorry. My typo. I missed the part of the sentence. Deleting... :)

Comment: I m not using radio group. I have made some changes to code.. Instead of OnShow event  i have used OnActivate event. In this case its working fine but if i minimize window or click on any other appication and visit my application then again one of radiobuttons will get checked. Is it mandatory to have one radiobutton checked?

Comment: Radio buttons are for mutually exclusive options. You are meant to have exactly one option selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First about using a radio group or not: if more then one radiobutton has the same parent, then that parent automatically acts like a *radio group*, whether you use a TRadioGroup component or not. So radio buttons with the same parent behave like they should do: none or only one can be selected.

Secondly, it is perfectly valid to reset a group of radio buttons to unselected/unchecked state. For a recent example, see [default radio option of edit rejection dialogue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110277).

I reproduced your problem, but I do not have an explaination. What happens is that when you show the form *again* (instead of recreating it again), then the focussed control is still that radio button. This focus somehow prevents changing the checked state. *Anyone any idea why? I cannot find it in the VCL source.*

The solution is to defocus the selected radio button. This can be done in three ways, in order of preference:

- Focus the control which appears first in the tab order list (which is good practice anyway):

  ```
  procedure TSubForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    SelectFirst;
    RadioButton1.Checked := False;
    RadioButton2.Checked := False;
  end;
  ```
- But when the radio button ís that first control, then set focus to the form itself:

  ```
    SetFocus;
    RadioButton1.Checked := False;
    ...
  ```
- Or set focus to any other control in case it makes sense:

  ```
    OKButton.SetFocus;
    RadioButton1.Checked := False;
    ...
  ```